# Invoking endpoints in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, huggingface-transformers

```
import json
import boto3

ENDPOINT_NAME = "huggingface-pytorch-inference-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
runtime= boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['data']
    print(payload)

    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,ContentType='application/json',Body=payload)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    return result
```

> [ERROR] ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
> "code": 400,
> "type": "InternalServerException",
> "message": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

I am trying to invoke the endpoints of hugging face model to create lambda function in AWS, I tried many methods but ending up with same error, can anyone please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: If you could provide some details of what you are calling this with then you may get more help.  Do you get an output from printing payload?  The fact the error relates to char 0 suggests that you are failing to pass the data, or are providing it in an incorrect format, so seeing what data you are passing may quickly identify the problem.

Comment: {
  "data": "people are going to office"
} #this is the event i am passing through it

Comment: I am calling the event in json format.

Comment: { "inputs": "people are going to office" } changing data to inputs solved the error thank you John